# Nested query on join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
   SELECT adminTags.Tag, URL, Votes 
     FROM `adminTags` 
LEFT JOIN `Tags` ON adminTags.Tag = Tags.Tag
```

I'm joining table adminTags with table tags.

How can I first

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `Tags` 
 WHERE URL = "$site"
```

and then join this to adminTags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean...

```
SELECT adminTags.Tag, URL, Votes FROM `adminTags` 
LEFT JOIN `Tags` ON adminTags.Tag = Tags.Tag AND Tags.URL = "$site"
```

I suspect you tried first to add `WHERE URL = "$site"` which will effectively make this an `INNER JOIN` (since the `WHERE` would not be satisfied without the `URL` also being satisfied.

Putting the condition in the `ON` resolves that — you're joining only when there's a match.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT adminTags.Tag, URL, Votes
FROM `adminTags` LEFT JOIN `Tags`
ON adminTags.Tag = Tags.Tag
WHERE `Tags`.URL = "$site"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT adminTags.Tag, adminTags.URL, adminTags.Votes FROM `Tags`
LEFT JOIN `adminTags` ON adminTags.Tag = Tags.Tag
WHERE adminTags.URL = "$site"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options when using an OUTER join, and the results can be very different so details matter.

```
   SELECT at.Tag, 
          t.url, t.votes
     FROM adminTags at
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.tag = at.tag
                AND t.url = $site
```

This query will apply the `t.url = $site` ***before the join is made***, giving you pre-filtered results.

```
   SELECT at.Tag, 
          t.url, t.votes
     FROM adminTags at
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.tag = at.tag
    WHERE t.url = $site
```

The query above applies the criteria ***after the join has been made***.  It does not "convert an OUTER JOIN into an INNER JOIN" -- it filters the result set after the `OUTER JOIN` has been made.

In this example, there's no difference between the result sets.  However, if the URL column say was not nullable (value could not be NULL) you could check for NULLs (which would tell you what `ADMINTAGS` don't have corresponding `TAGS` records:

```
   SELECT at.Tag, 
          t.url, t.votes
     FROM adminTags at
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.tag = at.tag
    WHERE t.url IS NULL
```

...whereas the following would return `NULL` for all references to `TAGS` (while not accurately demonstrating `ADMINTAGS` rows without related `TAGS` rows:

```
   SELECT at.Tag, 
          t.url, t.votes
     FROM adminTags at
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.tag = at.tag
                AND t.url IS NULL
```